# I need to remove duplicate vertices(adjacency list)

Tags: c++, class, stdvector, adjacency-list, stdlist

**File test.txt**

- 6 (This is the number of vertices)
- 1 4 (Еhe first is the number of the vertex, and the second is the number of the vertex to which the edge is being constructed.
- 1 6
- 2 1
- 2 3
- 2 4
- 2 5
- 3 2
- 3 5
- 4 1
- 4 2
- 4 5
- 5 2
- 5 3
- 5 4
- 6 1

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <list>

  using namespace std;

  class edge
  {
  private:
  int node2id, nodeid;
  public:
  edge(int id, int id2)
  {
      node2id = id2;
      nodeid = id;

  }

  int getnodeid()
  {
      return nodeid;
  }
  int getnodeid2()
  {
      return node2id;
  }

  };

  int main()
  { 
  int totalnode, node1, node2;
  ifstream input("test.txt");
  input >> totalnode;
  vector<list<edge>>adjList(totalnode);
  while (input >> node1 >> node2)
  {
      adjList[node1 - 1].push_back(edge(node2, node1));
  }

  int c = 1;
  vector<list<edge>>::iterator i;
  for (i = adjList.begin(); i != adjList.end(); i++)
  {
      cout << c << " -- ";
      list<edge>  li = *i;
      list<edge>::iterator iter;
      for (iter = li.begin(); iter != li.end(); iter++)
      {
          cout << "[" << (*iter).getnodeid() << "] ";
      }
      cout << endl;
      c++;
  }

  while (input >> node1 >> node2)
  {
      adjList[node1 - 1].push_back(edge(node1, node1));
  }

  cout << "\n";
  ```

And in this part, new vertices are created and I don't know how to remove the same ones.

```
vector<list<edge>>::iterator j;

for (j = adjList.begin(); j != adjList.end(); j++)
{


    //cout << c << " -- ";
    list<edge>  li = *j;
    list<edge>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = li.begin(); iter != li.end(); iter++)
    {

        cout << c <<" -- " << "[" << (*iter).getnodeid2() << "] " << "[" << (*iter).getnodeid() << "]\n";
        c++;

    }


}
return 0;
}
```

**Output**

Adjacency list will be created

```
1 -- [2] [4] [6]
2 -- [1] [3] [4] [5]
3 -- [2] [5]
4 -- [1] [2] [5]
5 -- [2] [3] [4]
6 -- [1]
```

These vertices were created, but for example, vertices 7 and 10 (and so on) have the same connections. And you need to make sure that there are no identical vertices.

```
7 -- [1] [2]
8 -- [1] [4]
9 -- [1] [6]
10 -- [2] [1]
11 -- [2] [3]
12 -- [2] [4]
13 -- [2] [5]
14 -- [3] [2]
15 -- [3] [5]
16 -- [4] [1]
17 -- [4] [2]
18 -- [4] [5]
19 -- [5] [2]
20 -- [5] [3]
21 -- [5] [4]
22 -- [6] [1]
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting your question correctly, but different vertices all having edges that connects to the same vertices doesn't make them the same vertex.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I think I poorly formulated the question. But if we take the example output as a basis, then vertices 7 and 10 have the same adjacency lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have so far, seems like you don't really need a `edge` class. All the information could be stored in `int` instead.

---

And to solve what you wanted, you could first store all the edges in an `std::vector<std::set<int>` like:

```
while (input >> node1 >> node2)
{
    adjList[node1 - 1].insert(node2);
}
```

By using a set, all the edges are stored in numerical ascending order. So instead of:

```
10 -- [2] [1]
```

You would have:

```
10 -- [1] [2]
```

Now you can just parse the vector into an `std::map`, like:

```
std::map<std::set<int>, int> tempMap;

for(auto i = 0; i < totalnode; ++i)
{
    s.try_emplace(adjList[i], i);
}
```

This would automatically get rid of node that already have another node with the same set of adjacent nodes (like you described in your question).

However, I'm only calling this a `tempMap` because at the moment, they are ordered by their adjacencies, not their name.

So what you could do is:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int>> adjMap;

for(auto& [key, value] : tempMap)
{
    adjMap.emplace(value, key);
}
```

Now you can loop through the entire map like:

```
for(auto& [node, edges] : adjMap
{
    std::cout << node << " -- ";
    for(auto& edge: edges)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << edge << "]";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

---

Side note, I notice you have written code like:

```
vector<list<edge>>::iterator i;
for (i = adjList.begin(); i != adjList.end(); i++) { // your loop }
```

Instead, you could just use:

```
for(auto it = adjList.begin(); it != adjList.end(); ++it) { // your loop }
    ^^^^
```

It automatically assign `i` with the appropriate iterator type for that container.

Or even in many case:

```
for(auto& item : adjList) { // your loop }
```

And you can use `item` in your loop the same way as `*i` from previous example.

Comment: Thank you so much!